# Using Visual Studio Installer, how do I create a shortcut in the install process to the CORRECT file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I managed to create an installer program for a .net 7 web console application.  It is a web server, technically, and the program interface is through the web browser for easy cross-platform building.
Using the Installer package available in Visual Studio, I created a branch to build a Windows installer in.  There is a problem, however.  I want to put a shortcut in the user's start menu that points to the generated console application.  I added a shortcut to "primary output" and ended up with a shortcut to the .dll.  This is not what I want.  I need something they can just double-click and launch.  Is there a way to change the primary output?

I have a standard project setup.  All folders are in their default locations.